# Afflix script not working while other js does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jscript with a fadeIn that is working, but my afflix isn't:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("i just got invoked");
  $(".navbar").affix({
    offset: {
      top: 10
    }
  });
  alert("i just got invoked2");
});
```

Both alerts are working, but the second one pops just after the first. I want to make my navbar stay at top always, in my css I have those rules:

```
.navbar {
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-size:10pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: fixed;

}

#my-navbar{
background:url(headers/macDark.jpg) no-repeat;  
    height: 800px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Is the css the problem? Yesterday I had a lot of people talking about linking and referring my js but thats not the problem since my other JS is working.

Comment: Did you put  `data-spy="affix"` on your `.navbar` component ?

Comment: yes, and I'm enabling it via JavaScript